# cast in sql server yyyy/mm/dd instead of dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: sql-server, datetime, casting

I have a script to insert 1000 rows of data in a table, in the datetime column I have this information.

```
CAST(N'2015-05-14 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime)
```

The problem is cast is trying to cast in dd/mm/yyyy format where the input is in yyyy/mm/dd format.

Comment: Which version of sql server ? In Version 2012, you have more possibilities.

Comment: Yes its 2012, but the problem is , i have everything with cast because its a script of a data to insert in a table, and its already written that way

Comment: Do you want to insert data with old format and then convert to the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `cast` when converting `varchar` to `datetime`, use `convert` instead, as `convert` takes in a date format.

```
convert(datetime, '2015-05-14 00:00:00.000', 121)
```

See more at:

http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

> its already written that way since i have a generated script of data to insert, so i cant change one by one, too many rows to insert

Are you unable to modify the script?  This seems like an easy find/replace.

> CAST(N'     ->     convert(datetime, '
>
> ' AS datetime)     ->     ', 121)

Comment: its already written that way since i have a generated script of data to insert, so i cant change one by one, too many rows to insert

Comment: Then use [`set dateformat ymd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) before your script.